# How to filter keydowns with rxjs?

Tags: javascript, keydown, rxjs

I need to get clean keydown/keyup events without repetitions. When you press a key keydown event happens, when you release - keyup. Without messy repeated keydowns.

Here's code:

```
var keyDowns = rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keydown');
var keyUps = rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keyup'); 
var keyActions = rx.Observable.merge(keyDowns, keyUps);

keyActions.subscribe(function(e) {
    console.log e
});
```

How to adapt it to do the job?

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to filter. What do you mean by repeated keydowns? Are you trying to match the key down with a key up?

Comment: When you press a key and hold it, normally you get repetitions, a lot of keydowns. I want to have 1 'press' event when key is physically pressed, and 1 'release' event when key is released. Sorry my English

Comment: And, yes, match between keyups and keydowns is needed

Comment: Here's [working example](http://jsbin.com/lawete/20/edit?js,console,output), but it seem to me not in rx-style. Still would like to know how to make it better. And there's bug on jsbin with coffescript sometimes, so just switch to js and then back to coffee if it happens.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Check out Federico's answer below for a much more elegant and idiomatic solution.**

---

You can avoid repeated items from an observable (as you see when a key is held) with [`distinctUntilChanged`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/distinctuntilchanged.md) which filters out values matching the last emitted value (where matching is determined by equality of emitted values or their values transformed by the `keySelector` callback argument).

In your case, this could look as simple as something like:

```
var keyDowns = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keydown');
var keyUps = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keyup');
var keyActions = Rx.Observable
    .merge(keyDowns, keyUps)
    .distinctUntilChanged(function(e) { return e.type + (e.key || e.which); });

keyActions.subscribe(function(e) {
    console.log(e.type, e.key || e.which, e.keyIdentifier);
});
```

but this falls short when holding multiple keys. In Chrome OS X, if I press and hold A, S, D, and then release A, S, D I get the following in the console:

```
keydown 65 U+0041
keydown 83 U+0053
keydown 68 U+0044
keyup 65 U+0041
keydown 68 U+0044
keyup 83 U+0053
keydown 68 U+0044
keyup 68 U+0044
```

Note the repetition of "keydown 68" (D) when releasing A and S. This is because `keydown` events only repeat for the most-recently pressed key. Using a similar idea to the one in your comment, we can instead try a custom filter which maintains a list of which keys have been pressed:

```
var keyDowns = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keydown');
var keyUps = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keyup');
var keyActions = Rx.Observable
    .merge(keyDowns, keyUps)
    .filter((function() {
        var keysPressed = {};
        return function(e) {
            var k = e.key || e.which;
            if (e.type == 'keyup') {
                delete keysPressed[k];
                return true;
            } else if (e.type == 'keydown') {
                if (keysPressed[k]) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    keysPressed[k] = true;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        };
    })());

keyActions.subscribe(function(e) {
    console.log(e.type, e.key || e.which, e.keyIdentifier);
});
```

Pressing and holding A, S, D, and then releasing A, S, D now gives:

```
keydown 65 U+0041
keydown 83 U+0053
keydown 68 U+0044
keyup 65 U+0041
keyup 83 U+0053
keyup 68 U+0044
```

which is similar to the approach you mentioned in the comment except that we're filtering the combined stream rather than pre-filtering such that the combined stream looks as we like it.

I'm not experienced enough with rx.js to assert that this is the best way to do this, but it certainly feels more in line with the Rx style. (Any comments appreciated.)

Comment: While this works, the code with state tracking is ** very ** unidiomatic.

Answer (score 24):

While it's nice it works, the solution by icio with state tracking is ** very ** unidiomatic. The proper [RxJs 5](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/) solution would be:

```
var keyDowns = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, "keydown")
var keyUps = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, "keyup")

var keyPresses = keyDowns
  .merge(keyUps)
  .groupBy(e => e.keyCode)
  .map(group => group.distinctUntilChanged(null, e => e.type))
  .mergeAll()
```

Explanation:

- Merge all keydown and keyup events for all the keys.
- Group them by key (keyCode). It creates an observable of observables where each sub-observable will contain all events for one key.
- Map each sub-observable to the distinctUntilChanged version of itself. Do it by event type, so that extra keydowns are skipped.
- Merge all the keys back to one observable

Comment: Can you please provide an example with pipeable operators which works exactly the same? I have troubles with union types.

Comment: It would be great an rxjs 6 version

Answer (score 4):

In RxJs 5, if you just want to filter a single key, it would be:

```
    import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs/observable/fromEvent';
    import { merge } from 'rxjs/operators/merge';
    import { distinctUntilChanged, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

    const keyDowns = fromEvent(document, 'keydown');
    const keyUps = fromEvent(document, 'keyup');

    const keyPresses = keyDowns.pipe(
        merge(keyUps),
        filter((e: KeyboardEvent) => e.keyCode === 17),
        distinctUntilChanged((x, y) => x.type == y.type)
    );

    keyPresses.subscribe((ctrlpress) => {
        this.holdingCtrl = ctrlpress.type === 'keydown';
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated answer for Rxjs 7 based on Federico's answer.

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs';

keyDowns = Rx.fromEvent(document, "keydown");
keyUps = Rx.fromEvent(document, "keyup");

keyPresses = Rx.merge(this.keyUps, this.keyDowns).pipe(
  Rx.groupBy((e: any) => e.keyCode),
  Rx.map((group: any) => group.pipe(
    Rx.distinctUntilChanged((prev: any, curr: any) => prev.type === curr.type)
  )),
  Rx.mergeAll()
);
```